# Power BI: Filter a table based on measure with multiple OR's

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, measure

I am trying to filter a table based on the measure pasted below. A row from the table 'sheet1' should be shown in the table if:

- the column 'parent link' contains the string as defined AND
- the column 'CRA intake status' equals "To Do" OR
- the column 'Eligible for Capitalisation' equals "No" or is blank OR
- the column 'Solution Intent status' equals "To Do" or "Undefined".

This code gives me the following error 'The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.' and I don't know how to solve it. Could anyone help out?

```
Filter missing requirements =
VAR MTMB = "ABN-1095"
VAR Filtermissing =
FILTER('Sheet1',
    CONTAINSSTRING('Sheet1'[Parent Link], MTMB) &&
    'Sheet1'[CRA Intake Status] = "To Do" ||
    'Sheet1'[Eligible for Capitalisation] = "No" ||
    ISBLANK('Sheet1'[Eligible for Capitalisation]) ||
    'Sheet1'[Solution Intent status] = "Undefined" ||
    'Sheet1'[Solution Intent status] = "To Do"
    )

RETURN
    Filtermissing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your measure is returning a table - maybe you are after...

```
Filter missing requirements =
  VAR MTMB = "ABN-1095"
  VAR Filtermissing = 
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('Sheet1'),
      FILTER('Sheet1',
        CONTAINSSTRING('Sheet1'[Parent Link], MTMB) &&
        'Sheet1'[CRA Intake Status] = "To Do" ||
        'Sheet1'[Eligible for Capitalisation] = "No" ||
        ISBLANK('Sheet1'[Eligible for Capitalisation]) ||
        'Sheet1'[Solution Intent status] = "Undefined" ||
        'Sheet1'[Solution Intent status] = "To Do"
      )
    )
  RETURN
    Filtermissing
```

?